# Scrapy handle 302 redirections

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to crawl a web site using a scrapy CrawlSpider the problem is that the website keeps redirecting me in a random pattern meaning that a url might load sometimes and sometimes it's redirected to a certain page I tried changing my user-agent, Tried to mimic the behavior of the browser by  creating an http header similar to the one sent by the browser and even when I used crawlera to send the requests nothing solved my problem. I'd be thankful if someone guided me through this

Console:

```
2017-11-06 02:11:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-11-06 02:11:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-11-06 02:11:14 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-11-06 02:11:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html> from <GET http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html>
2017-11-06 02:11:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html> (referer: None)
2017-11-06 02:11:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html> from <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/sitemap.html>
2017-11-06 02:11:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html> (referer: http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html)
2017-11-06 02:11:34 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.sears.com/gifts/b-1020009> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-11-06 02:11:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sears.com/seasonal-christmas/b-1100100> (referer: http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html)
2017-11-06 02:11:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sears.com/toys-games/b-1020010> (referer: http://www.sears.com/en_intnl/dap/shopping-tourism.html)
2017-11-06 02:11:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html> from <GET http://www.sears.com/home-decor-decorative-accents/b-1348893716>
2017-11-06 02:11:58 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html> from <GET http://www.sears.com/tvs-electronics-home-theater-audio-musical-instruments-guitars-string-instruments/b-5000861>
2017-11-06 02:12:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html> from <GET http://www.sears.com/tvs-electronics-gaming/b-1347529268>
```

Comment: Sears probably requires you to solve a captcha if you visit from any non-residential IP address (like the ones used by Crawlera). You'll have to solve the captcha to bypass the check or test if the appropriate cookie can be copied from your own browser.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I disabled crawlera and tried to run the spider on my own IP go the same result, actually the console log I attached is resulting from running the spider on my IP

Comment: I got the captcha immediately when visiting the website with my typical browser. Try pulling the cookie from your home browser.

Comment: Isn't scrapy supposed to handle cookies by default?

Comment: The cookie is set by the website when you complete the captcha. There'd be no point to having a webpage called `botmanagement.html` if it was completely trivial to bypass.

Comment: @MohamedElmahdi, this is a scraping protection. They will have different checks on server side. They may be using a professional scraping protection software or have custom rules. With experiment you need to find out what those rules are. Like only X request per min, max Y requests/IP and if they are not happy the redirect you to a captcha page to make sure you are a human

Comment: You can clearly see they are redirecting you to the Captcha page http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html ... You need to use rotating proxies, ... Whenever you see you are redirected to that Captcha page, just re-schedule that request with a new IP

Comment: Thx for the replies, Actually I'm using a crawlera account to handle the proxy rotations, delays, etc... but still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of proxies:

- When you use `parse` to parse the html

  - Use `if response.url == """http://www.sears.com/en_us/botmanagement.html""":` to detect if you have been redirected to a `reCAPCHA` page.
  - Use Selenium with Scrapy(Selenium can control browser directly, so you will be able to watch the whole scraping process and manually pass the reCAPCHA)([This is an example of how to use selenium with Scrapy](https://gist.github.com/XetRAHF/45fd4a41ae68c58d9118a68769a444ef))
  - Slow down your scraping speed in order to prevent spider detection
- Public proxies

  - [Gather proxies](http://www.gatherproxy.com/en)